# Personal R Package for JDBC Connections

Tags: java, r, jdbc, package, rjava

I was hoping someone could suggest on how this problem could be approached.
I'm trying to build a personal package to easily make JDBC connections, and I am having trouble with getting my package to find the driver files to make these connections.

I would like to either
   1) include JDBC driver (jar) files with the package, or
   2) define the path in the environment variable (Sys.setenv) and refer to this path within the package (Sys.getenv).

I've tried numerous ways but I couldn't get the first approach to work when I tried storing these files in inst/java.
I also couldn't get the second way to work as JDBC connections return as NULL.
I can't think of why this isn't working as it prints out the path correctly.

Would anyone know how to approach this problem?

Comment: I wouldn't approach this problem myself, I would use an already existing R package which can connect with JDBC.  That being said, maybe you can update your question and let us know why you need to do this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using DBI and RJDBC to make JDBC connections within my package. What I'm trying to do is just automate some connections using these packages. For instance, I want to be able to type conn <- connection_mssql(database1) or conn2 <-
 connection_postgres(database2) without having to define driver path, database type, etc. every single time. Also annoying when I am running R on multiple machines.

Comment: this https://github.com/hrbrmstr/metis might provide some help @user7137914

Comment: I remember seeing something on using the config package to source connection info from YAML files recently, but I can't seem to find it right now... this however might also be useful https://www.rstudio.com/resources/videos/database-best-practices/

Comment: The RH2 package provides a driver for the H2 database using RJDBC and includes the entire database right in the package.  Try following that.

Comment: Thanks all for your input! I've been trying to read the code and understand what's going on for both metis and RH2 packages. I'll comment when I have this figured out. It seems like the two packages call jar files in different ways and I need to better understand S4 programming.

Comment: @DaveRGP Thanks for mentioning the YAML files. I'll see if I can set additional variables and get the package to work. This site seems helpful: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r/

Comment: Found It! https://db.rstudio.com/portable-code/#deploying-with-config-package @user7137914